# Azure DevOps: Doesn't post debug information to the symbol server

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, debug-symbols

We recently swapped to NetCore projects and made needed changes to the pipeline. The pipeline task PublishSymbols@2 doesn't seem to be publishing symbols for our NuGet packages. At least, the Debugger isn't working anymore. Should I be using another task? Are my parameters wrong?

The pipeline sends out a warning that
`##[warning]No files selected for indexing.`

It also has the log file line
`[Symbol App][INFO]    2021-07-02T11:41:51.7320634+00:00  Published 1 files.`

```
projectsNuGet: |
  **/ParkInd_Modular_CommonPlugins.@(csproj|pdb)
    

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: Publish debug information to symbol servers
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: |
      $(projectsNuGet)
      !*.csproj
      !**/obj/**
    SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code didn't work because my dll had a different name than my csproj. Apparently the name of a dll is based on the AssemblyName not the csproj name. It makes sense.